# adding leading zeros to a list AND assign the modified values back to the variable in the data frame

Tags: r, leading-zero

The dataset I'm working with is a .csv file which has 13 columns with the following headers (bold), and 302 rows : **id** : 1,2,..., 302), **source_code:** : AAA, BBB, CCC., **date,day, month, year, time,hour, minute, second,latitude, longitude, inscriptions:** NA, 1 or 0.

I want the column of IDs (1, 2, 3,...,302) to have 3 digit numbers, with prevailing zeros when necessary (001, 002, ..., 010, ..., 302).

This is what I have done:

`data<-read.csv("C:/TFM/corrected_filtered_coordinates.csv")`

`str(data)`

> #'data.frame': 302 obs. of 13 variables:

> #$ id : int 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...

`data$id <- as.numeric(data$id)`

`sprintf("%03d", data$id)`

> #sprintf("%03d", data$id)

> #[1] "001" "002" "003" "004" "005" "006" "007" "008" "009" "010"

`str(data)`

> #'data.frame': 302 obs. of 13 variables:

> #$ id : int 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...

So far, I have found 2 functions that work (A list with the transformed IDs appears in the console after I run either of them):

`formatC(data$id, width = 3, format = "d", flag = "0")`
and
`sprintf("%03d", data$id)`

**HOWEVER**

when I display the data after running either of those functions, using `data` or `str(data)` , the IDs still appear without the leading zeros!

I have tried changing the IDs to characters `#data$id <- as.character(data$id)` and as numeric `data$id <- as.numeric(data$id)` *before* running the functions...but nothing appears to work!

**How can I make the IDs keep the changes?**  I am failing to assign the modified values back to the variable in the data frame

Thank you in advance!!!

Comment: Do you have a `list` column or a vector.  Can you show the issue with `sprintf("%03d", data$id)`.  If you have a character column, then use `sprintf("%03d", as.numeric(data$id))`

Comment: are you doing `data$id <- format(...)` or `data$id <- sprintf(...)` ? Just doing `sprintf()` or `format()` and *then* changing `id` to character won't help ...  A [mcve] should be easy to construct and would clarify things a lot.

Comment: @akrun I used `sprintf("%03d", as.numeric(data$id))` ,  which showed me the list of converted IDs in the console ( just as when I used `formatC(data$id, width = 3, format = "d", flag = "0")` and `sprintf("%03d", data$id)` ), but then when checking if it has had an effect on the data by using `str(data)` , the original IDs come out! How can I make the changed be saved in the data?

Comment: @BenBolker I changed the ID to character _before_ using the functions.. and I also tried changing it to numeric _before_ applying the functions. The problem is that the changes ( ie: making the ids have leading zeros, 3 digits in total) are not being shown when I check the data... ( either by running `data` or `str(data)` ) .  I need to find a way that the changes are shown in the data. Am I making any sense? Thank you all for your patience!

Comment: we really, really need a [mcve] so we can see what you're doing.   This could be as simple as `dd <- data.frame(id=c(1,2,3,10)); dd$id <- sprintf("%03d", dd$id); str(dd)`.  Verbal descriptions of what you did are always subject to imprecision ...

Comment: As @BenBolker mentioned, it is not clear without a small reproducible example.

Comment: okay, this is what I have done::: `data<-read.csv("C:/TFM/corrected_filtered_coordinates.csv")` ; `str(data)` ## 'data.frame': 302 obs. of 13 variables: ## $ id : int 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ... ; `data$id <- as.numeric(data$id)` ; `sprintf("%03d", data$id)`  ; ##> sprintf("%03d", data$id) ## [1] "001" "002" "003" "004" "005" "006" "007" "008" "009" "010" ; `str(data)` ##'data.frame': 302 obs. of 13 variables: ## $ id : int 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...

Comment: please edit your question to include this information. For what it's worth, the example you've given is **not** reproducible (we don't have your input file), but it does seem from what you've got here that my answer should solve your problem ...

Comment: The question is edited :) Does it make more sense now? Also, your answer solved my problem!! I had to type `data$id <-` _before_ `sprintf("%03d", data$id)`  THANK YOU!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guessing at this a bit, but it sounds like you are failing to assign the modified values back to the variable in the data frame.

```
dd <- data.frame(id=c(1,2,3,10))
dd$id <- sprintf("%03d", dd$id)
str(dd)
## 'data.frame':    4 obs. of  1 variable:
## $ id: chr  "001" "002" "003" "010"
```

- I used `dd` rather than `data` for the name of the data frame; `data` is also the name of a built-in function in R, and it's best practice to avoid it

Comment: This solved my problem!! Thank you for your help and patience!!

Comment: If this solves your problem, you are encouraged to click the check-mark to accept it ...